Custom User Role and Editing a Custom Post Type
I have created a custom post type in Wordpress using this code...
register_post_type( 'workorder',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Work Order' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Work Order' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'page-attributes', 'author'),
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'capability_type' => array('workorder','workorders'),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
    )
);

This works great to add in the custom post type. I have created a custom user role like this...
add_role('work_orders_new',
    'Work Order Manager New',
    array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => false,
        'delete_posts' => false,
        'publish_posts' => false,
        'upload_files' => true,
    )
);

This works great to create the custom user role.  I have then used this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ to edit the user roles.  I have added these user roles
read
delete_others_workorders
delete_private_workorders
delete_published_workorders
delete_workorders
edit_others_workorders
edit_private_workorders
edit_published_workorders
edit_workorders
publish_workorders
read_private_workorders

via the plugin.  The issue is that when that user is logged in they are able to see the Work Orders custom post type and can see the list of available posts but when they click on a post to edit it then it takes them to a page that says "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."
If I give the user this capability "edit_posts" - Then they are able to edit that post successfully.  I don't really want to give this user edit_posts because they are then able to see "posts" and "comments" in the admin dashboard.  Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

This doesn't answer the question, but User Role Editor lets you create roles directly in the plugin. Why have a custom script? Try moving all the functionality into URE, and see if that helps.

Sorry should have mentioned this earlier.  I tried both having the plugins create the roles and assign the capabilities and then doing both of those things in code as well.  Now I'm at the code creating the roles and the plugin assigning the capabilities.  I'm not opposed to doing it any way its just that nothing I've tried works.

try to add the 3 singular capabilities edit_workorder read_workorder delete_workorder

Still no luck I added those three and then removed "edit_posts" and I got the "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."  After I added "edit_posts" back that message went away.  So still not working.
